# Place a div with an image on top of another div with an embeded video

Tags: css, html, video-embedding

I am trying to make an HTML page to loop a playlist of videos with an overlay of twitter messages corresponding to some tag.

I thought I could make it for a web environment so I tried combining HTML and CSS.

The way I am traing to make it works is by embeding a WMPlayer object with 100% width and height and placing on the top of that layer another layer with a background and some PHP code to load the tweets.

But it is not working at all... not trying with an image, even trying with just text. I think the problem might be that it is not possible to place anything on the top of the video or, of course, my code is wrong.

Here it is:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}

.video{   
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;;
   position: relative;
    background: #0f0;
}
.tweets {    
    width:50%;
    height:350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background: #f00;
    z-index:100
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="video">
            <OBJECT id="VIDEO" width="100%" height="100%" 
                CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
                type="application/x-oleobject">
                    <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="http://www.falange.es/videos/video.mp4">
                <PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True">
                <PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True">
                <PARAM name="uiMode" value="none">
                <PARAM name="PlayCount" value="9999">
                <PARAM name="WMode" value="opaque">
                <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
                name="mediaplayer1" autostart="true" width="100%" height="100%" transparentstart="1" SHOWSTATUSBAR="1" 
                    loop="0" controller="true" src="http://www.falange.es/videos/video.mp4" stretchToFit="true" ></embed>
            </OBJECT>       
            <div class="tweets">
                Tweets here.
            </div>          
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: as far as I know float:top is not valid css and does not do anything. what you need is z-index

Comment: You are right. But with or without "float:top" it doesn't do anything. I guess I was just desperated and I tried almost anything regarding positioning...

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give your `<body>` a height of 100% than the `<div>` will stretch to it - http://jsfiddle.net/z5kGQ/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.video {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   background: beige;
}

.tweets {
    width:100%;
    min-height:150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: It's also working. I found out my problem is VLC plugin. On IE and with WMPlayer Plugin it works although the video -not the video-object- it is always on top.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting z-index:100 for example on the tweet div

```
.tweets {
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    min-height:350px;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(img.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

remove style tag fro your object tag, it would be good if you can provide a jsfiddle with a working video and sample text to overlay on top. I have a feeling the object tag will be hard to deal with when it comes to overlays, but I am not 100% sure until I can test it

Edit - Try setting the wmode=transparent in object tag params

```
<PARAM name="WMode" value="transparent">
```

Comment: As the other examples, also work on IE with WMPlayer pluging but it is not possible to overlay the video. It overlays the video layer but not the video by itself.